# JQuery validation with MVC 4 form doesn't work.

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate

I'm using MVC 4 form and I want to make some validations to my inputs.
Since my MVC strongly type model is a little complicated, I want to use only JQuery validation method without any using of Attributes properties.

When I running my page I can see the alert message, but IE10 tells me:
"Object doesn't support property or method 'validate'".

Besides, Chrome also shows the alert, but when I click on "Submit" and leave my FirstName input blank, nothing comes up and the form is submitted.
Should I define my errors messages somewhere? what am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

This is my `<head>` section in **_Layout.cshtml** :

```
<head>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

This is my `<body>` section in **EditClient.cshtml** (using the layout above):

```
<body>
<script src="../../Scripts/EditClient.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
@using (Html.BeginForm("EditClient", "Reviewer", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "ClientForm" }))
{
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Client.Person1.FirstName)
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="form-submit" />
}
</body>
```

This is my **EditClient.js** for the form validation:

```
$("document").ready(function () {

    alert('Test Alert');    //Showing OK
    $("#ClientForm").validate(); //IE10 doesn't recognize the method
    $("#Client_Person1_FirstName").rules("add", { required: true, maxlength: 20, messages: { required: "Title required", maxlength: "Must be under 20 characters"} });

});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RequiredFieldValidator is not working properly with jQuery UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25506846/requiredfieldvalidator-is-not-working-properly-with-jquery-ui)

Answer (score 0):

Try defining the validation rules like that:

```
$("document").ready(function () {
    $("#ClientForm").validate({
        rules: {
            'Client.Person1.FirstName':
           {
                required: true,
                maxlength: 20
            }
        },
        messages:
        {
            'Client.Person1.FirstName':
           {
                required: 'Title required',
                maxlength: 'Must be under 20 characters'
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: still the same, is there something missing? Maybe a submit handler or something?

Comment: No, you don't need any submit handler. This should work, it is the same as the code shown in the documentation of the plugin. Are there some javascript errors in the Chrome console? Also make sure that the `jquery.validate.min.js` script exists at the specified location. Look at the Network tab to see if there aren't some 404 errors when rendering your view.

Comment: The Chrome Console tells me: "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'validate'", and the Network Tab shows all linked ok...

Comment: Have you confirmed that `jquery.validate.min.js` script exists at the specified location? It looks like this file doesn't exist or is not properly included.

Comment: Problem Solved. At the bottom of my _Layout.cshtml I had: @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery"). Removing it solved my problem. Thank you!