# RequiredFieldValidator is not working properly with jQuery UI

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui

I am working on ASP.NET Web Forms application. I have a pretty big form with a lot of fields so I want to take as much advantage as possible from the built-in server controls in `Web Forms`. Also, because the form is too big I logically have separated it into three parts using  jQuery UI 1-8-24 and an accordion menu. I also use a DatePicker on this page so my page looks like this:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#accordion").accordion();
        $(".inpt-date").datepicker();
    });
    window.history.pushState('obj', '', 'myPage.aspx');
</script>
```

So it's working fine, I've implmeneted a lot of logic on this page and everything was working fine util the moment I stated to add `RequiredFieldValidator` For example :

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtEnforcementCase" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="RequiredFieldValidator2"
    ControlToValidate="txtEnforcementCase"
    Display="Static"
    Text="*"
    ErrorMessage="This field is required!"
    runat="server"/>
```

I think nothing out of the ordinary since I'm using examples from MSDN and the validations are pretty simple so I the standard implementation works for me.

However when I add the `RequiredFieldValidator` I lose all the styling from the jQuery UI and I get this error in the console :

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

I tried to comment and uncomment the `JS`code on the page. If I use only:

```
window.history.pushState('obj', '', 'myPage.aspx');
```

Everything's working fine, but no matter if I use both - the date picker and the accordion, or only one of them I lose the jQuery UI styling and get the error pointing to the row where I have `$("#accordion").accordion();` or `$(".inpt-date").datepicker();` depending on which one is commented and which not. I'm pretty sure there's some problem when I try to use jQuery UI and `RequiredFieldValidator` together. While searching for solution I found a partial one which was just for the `datepicker` which doesn't work for me because I use other jQuery UI methods and also, if I find partial solutions for the `accordion` and the `datepicker` later on I may want to use something else then I'll have to find workaround for that too, so.. is there a way to make a client side validation in `Windows Forms` using the build-in controls together with jQuery UI?

Answer (score 4):

The `RequiredFieldValidator` from ASP.NET uses jQuery clientside which needs to be registered first (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16660900/webforms-unobtrusivevalidationmode-requires-a-scriptresourcemapping-for-jquery)).

Apparently, ASP.NET injects a `<script>` reference to jQuery in the first part of the form.

If you registered your own `<script>` tags inside of the `<head>` of your page (first jQuery then jQuery UI), this effectively means you're losing your jQuery  UI bindings because jQuery is referenced again after the `<head>` thanks to WebForms.

The solution is to reference your scripts (jQuery, jQuery UI, and any custom scripts) at the **end** of the page, for example after the form element.