# ASP:RequiredFieldValidator and jQuery incompatibility

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I have some jQuery plugins running on my page (i.e. tabs). When I add an `<asp:requiredfieldvalidator>` the jQuery functionality stops working... any ideas?

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mobile' of undefined at
>   Object.initAnimation (zozo.tabs.js:1050) at ZozoTabs.init
>   (zozo.tabs.js:799) at HTMLDivElement. (zozo.tabs.js:2122)
>   at Function.each (jquery-2.1.4.js:374) at jQuery.fn.init.each
>   (jquery-2.1.4.js:139) at jQuery.fn.init.$.fn.zozoTabs
>   (zozo.tabs.js:2120) at HTMLDocument.
>   (PatientRegistration.js:18) at fire (jquery-2.1.4.js:3099) at
>   Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-2.1.4.js:3211) at
>   Function.ready (jquery-2.1.4.js:3417)

```
if (jQuery.browser.mobile) { 
    //_base.settings.event = zozo.events.touchend; 
    _base.settings.shadows = false; 
} 
if ($.zozo.core.support.css.transition === false) { 
    _base.settings.animation.type = zozo.animation.types.jquery; 
    if (jQuery.browser.mobile) { 
         _base.settings.animation.duration = 0; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Could you get a snapshot of your source code?

Comment: i m getting this error, Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mobile' of undefined
    at Object.initAnimation (zozo.tabs.js:1050)
    at ZozoTabs.init (zozo.tabs.js:799)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (zozo.tabs.js:2122)
    at Function.each (jquery-2.1.4.js:374)
    at jQuery.fn.init.each (jquery-2.1.4.js:139)
    at jQuery.fn.init.$.fn.zozoTabs (zozo.tabs.js:2120)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (PatientRegistration.js:18)
    at fire (jquery-2.1.4.js:3099)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-2.1.4.js:3211)
    at Function.ready (jquery-2.1.4.js:3417)

Comment: if (jQuery.browser.mobile) {
                //_base.settings.event = zozo.events.touchend;
                _base.settings.shadows = false;
            }

            if ($.zozo.core.support.css.transition === false) {
                _base.settings.animation.type = zozo.animation.types.jquery;
                if (jQuery.browser.mobile) {
                    _base.settings.animation.duration = 0;
                }
            }

Comment: all this happens when i add the asp required field validator, if i remove it, everything works just fine

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RequiredFieldValidator is not working properly with jQuery UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25506846/requiredfieldvalidator-is-not-working-properly-with-jquery-ui)

Comment: Also duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16660900/webforms-unobtrusivevalidationmode-requires-a-scriptresourcemapping-for-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been answered elsewhere on Stack Overflow:

[Answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25506846/requiredfieldvalidator-is-not-wrorking-properly-with-jquery-ui/25892934#25892934):

> The `RequiredFieldValidator` from ASP.NET uses jQuery clientside which
>   needs to be registered first (see here).
>
> Apparently, ASP.NET injects a `<script>` reference to jQuery in the
>   first part of the form.
>
> If you registered your own `<script>` tags inside of the `<head>` of your
>   page (first jQuery then jQuery UI), this effectively means you're
>   losing your jQuery UI bindings because jQuery is referenced again
>   after the `<head>` thanks to WebForms.
>
> The solution is to reference your scripts (jQuery, jQuery UI, and any
>   custom scripts) at the end of the page, for example after the form
>   element.

[Answer 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16660900/webforms-unobtrusivevalidationmode-requires-a-scriptresourcemapping-for-jquery/16705149#16705149)

> You need a web.config key to enable the pre 4.5 validation mode.
>
> More Info on **[ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh975440.aspx)**:
>
> Specifies how ASP.NET globally enables the built-in validator controls
>   to use unobtrusive JavaScript for client-side validation logic.
>
> Type: UnobtrusiveValidationMode
>
> Default value: None
>
> Remarks: If this key value is set to **"None"** [default], the ASP.NET
>   application will use the **pre-4.5 behavior** (JavaScript inline in the
>   pages) for client-side validation logic. If this key value is set to
>   **"WebForms"**, ASP.NET uses **HTML5 data-attributes and late bound
>   JavaScript from an added script reference** for client-side validation
>   logic.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> <appSettings>
>   <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
> </appSettings
> ```